# How should I unit test this

Tags: sql, database, unit-testing, testing, entity

I have an entity which has 15 members. There are various types of members with various rules applied to them, some allow nulls and some others don't. Here is the database entity:

```
tbl_items(
item_id bigint identity(1,1) not null primary key,
item_category bigint null foreign key references tbl_categories(category_id) on delete set null,
item_model nvarchar(50) not null,
item_brand nvarchar(50) not null,
item_color nvarchar(20) not null,
item_made_in nvarchar(20) null,
item_desc nvarchar(100) null,
item_price decimal not null,
item_image varbinary(max) null,
item_monetary_unit nvarchar(10) not null,
item_rating int null,
item_date datetime not null,
item_quantity int not null
)
```

Unit testing all of the states that data entries can possibly have will make my unit test class (ItemTest) to have more than 1000 lines of code. So do I need to write a test method for each data state? Or should I only consider invalid states for writing test methods? Like having null while the property is not nullable.

Comment: When you say "unit testing all of the states", what do you mean by that? Obvious things to test would be supply random values to the table to see if it holds the water. PK and FK tests are as important. Some more clarity on your question will help us understand it better.

Comment: id might be a null string, character string, negative number, zero, bigger than bigint size. should you write test method for each of these states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using NUnit or something similar, there are two concepts that would help with this:

1. Test Cases allow you to pass in parameters to a factored out test method: http://nunit.org/?p=testCase&r=2.5
2. Test Theories allow you to automatically create all possible inputs.  Warning: these can create very slow-running tests so use sparingly and carefully. http://nunit.org/index.php?p=theory&r=2.5

As far as what you should unit test, the answer to that question varies greatly.  Some people write cross-layer acceptance tests at the controller layer.  Some people mock out all dependencies and write isolated unit tests.  You have to see what you and your team want to do and try out different strategies.  Personally, for a situation like what you described, I'd write a generic test for your validation function(s).  Then, write a TestCase for all truly distinct cases.

Comment: thanks really helpfull, but what should i unit test? mappings? validations? bussiness rules?

Comment: updated the answer with my opinion on that, but the answer really does vary depending on team and project

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you testing? if you are testing the mapping from the object to the database, I'd write a test demonstrating that I can insert data so that the values from the object end up in the right database fields, and quit there.

Comment: well i'm just starting the unit testing. should i unit test mappings, validations and bussiness rules? i mean should you unit test "everything"? if yes, that will take a lot of time and will triple size the project in terms of writing code.

Comment: Ideally should be targeting the Business Rules in your Unit Tests. This gives you more value IMO.

Comment: @Raj: yes. since he was going on about nulls I figured there must be no business logic to test, otherwise he would be doing it.